# Symfony exception when registering new Doctrine event subscriber (SoftDeleteable)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I'm using Symfony 2.3 with Sonata Admin Bundle with [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) (which is enabled by [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)). I enabled, configured and successfully tested SoftDeleteable and Timestampable components.

Now, when I try adding another Doctrine event subscriber using Symfony tagged service, it seems as the softdeleteable listener is being disabled.

My service:

```
my.contact.listener.tag:
    class: My\ContactBundle\EventListener\TagListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setTagManager, [ @fpn_tag.tag_manager ] ]
```

Subscriber:

```
namespace My\ContactBundle\EventListener;


use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Taggable;
use FPN\TagBundle\Entity\TagManager;

class TagListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var TagManager
     */
    private $tagManager;

    /**
     * @param \FPN\TagBundle\Entity\TagManager $tagManager
     */
    public function setTagManager($tagManager)
    {
        $this->tagManager = $tagManager;
    }

    /**
     * Load tags for Taggable entities
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof Taggable) {
            $this->tagManager->loadTagging($entity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save tags for Taggable entities
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof Taggable) {
            $this->tagManager->saveTagging($entity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save tags for Taggable entities
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof Taggable) {
            $this->tagManager->saveTagging($entity);
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'prePersist',
            'preUpdate',
            'postLoad',
        );
    }
}
```

In each request I get exception:

```
Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!
```

If I disable my subscriber, the problem is gone. How to enable my event subscriber and have softdeleteable too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem as you do today.

The problem is that `fpn_tag.tag_manager` depends on `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`, but the `TagListener` is a dependency of `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` if you tag it with `doctrine.event_subscriber`. Thus creating a circular dependency. But this is not detected by the service container, instead it tries to add the events *after* the doctrine connection service is returned. See more details [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8425).

There are two ways to fix this

1. You can inject the service container into the `TagListener`, then load `fpn_tag.tag_manager` on demand.
2. Create a listener on `kernel.request` event, then manually add the event subscriber to the entity manager.

A side note, I'd recommend against calling `saveTagging` inside `preUpdate` and `prePersist` events. Because `saveTagging` does a implicit flush, which is not safe to call in these events.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. Reward bounty for you in 23 hours.

Comment: Oh, don't load the tags in `postLoad` either. Just got bitten by this today. Because if you are doing a DQL query, `postLoad` will be called when an entity is hydrated but before any association is created (see notes [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events). So if you `loadTagging` here, the hydrator will somehow lose some required data to continue populate other associations. And you will be scratching your head wondering why like I did.