# Configuring DoctrineExtensions-Taggable in Symfony fullstack with config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having difficulty configuring the Doctrine Extension Taggable provided here:
https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable

My project is using Symfony 2 Fullstack and my configuration is using yaml while my doctrine entities are using annotation. I installed DoctrineExtensions using composer. Adding "fpn/doctrine-extensions-taggable": "dev-master" to the require section on composer.json and then running `composer update`. This installed without issue.

I then become lost at this section: https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable#setup-doctrine

I understand that the metadata is a Doctrine Entity however as previously mentioned I am using yaml for my symfony configuration as well as entity managers. Here is the excerpt from my config.yml file:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: main
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            main:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    VendorMainBundle:
                        prefix: Vendor\MainBundle\Entity
            taggable:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    taggable:
                        type: xml
                        prefix: DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity
                        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fpn/doctrine-extensions-taggable/metadata
```

However, when I run `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info --em=taggable` I get the error:

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                                                           
  You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.
```

Should the above command show the mappings described in the [xml files](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable/tree/master/metadata)?
Thereby allowing me to update the schema in the database?

I used this documenation as reference for the config.yml file: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration

I also added this under the config.yml in order to setup the TagListener. Is this correct?

```
services:
    taggable:
        class: DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\TagListener
```

**EDIT [@Grimv01k]:**
The TagListener requires an argument passed that is an instance of the TagManager Object. I created another service to handle that as follows and passed it to the TagListener:

```
tag.manager:
        class: DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\TagManager
        tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        arguments:
            entity.manager: @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    taggable:
        class: DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\TagListener
        arguments:
            manager: @tag.manager
```

The TagManager requires an argument of the entityManager however by doing so results in error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]                                    
  Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection".
```

Across the web it's recommended to resolve this error by passing @service_container and in the constructor of the object pull out the entity_manager, however being a vendor I'd prefer not to modify their code. Is there another way?

Comment: What you got running `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info`, without specifying `--em`?

Comment: It will list all of the Entities defined in the MainBundle. These are defined in the bundle under Entity folder using Annoation.

Comment: Found something that might give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493779/symfony-exception-when-registering-new-doctrine-event-subscriber-softdeleteable

Answer (score 0):

Just guess: maybe that happens becuse you haven't got `tags` applied in service, and Doctrine doesn't use this in your complier pass. Try to do it like this:

```
services:
taggable:
    class: DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\TagListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

Comment: Updated question after applying your answer. This seemed to get me a little further but ran into another issue as a result.

Comment: As I've searched, even guys who write extensions injecting `@service_container` and using it inside. Will try to find more. Shame `Gedmo` don't have `taggable`, would have been easier.